# Error to load the webpage in flash action script 2.0

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

Error to load the webpage in flash action script 2.0.

In flash i wrote the actionscript in button

```
getURL('www.google.in',"_blank");
```

If i click the action button its automatically redirect to browser and open the website.

Code is working fine in my system. In another system is browser open the URL path like file:///F|/Sharing/www.google.in

Comment: It is higly unclear what your trying to ask. Can you reformulate?

Comment: In flash i wrote the actionscript in button `(getURL('www.google.in',"_blank");)` If i click the button its automatically redirect to browser and open the page.  Code is working fine in my system. In another system is browser open the URL path like file:///F|/Sharing/www.google.in

Comment: You should edit your question instead of adding comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should indicate `http://` ( or `https://`, `mailto:`, ... ) otherwise flash will consider your URL as a local file.

So your [`getURL()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118ccf9c47f-7fc9.html) can be like this :

```
getURL('http://www.google.in', '_blank');
```

Hope that can help.